# Deleting "pseudo" sql database from backup with special caracter '#' in the name leads to "Incorrect database name" error

Tags: mariadb

By mistake, my MariaDB SQL server created a database with the `#` character:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+---------------------------------------+
| Database                              |
+---------------------------------------+
| #mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023 |
```

This prevents `mysql_upgrade` to upgrade my database:

```
root@0900328dd668:/# mysql_upgrade -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
Major version upgrade detected from 10.3.11-MariaDB to 10.5.22-MariaDB. Check required!
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.transaction_registry                         OK
mysql.user                                         OK
Phase 2/7: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Phase 3/7: Fixing views
mariadb-check: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name '#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023' when selecting the database
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

So I tried to delete it using the CLI, which doesn't work even with backticks:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> drop database `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023`;
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name '#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023'
```

Using DBeaver, it generates

```
DROP SCHEMA `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023`;
```

which also leads to the same error. So I tried to search the data directory inside the Docker container:

```
root@0900328dd668:/# find /var/lib/mysql -name \*backup\*
/var/lib/mysql/_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023
```

It contains a SQL file, which doesn't name any database name (it was a mysql dump). It looks like MariaDB created this `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023` database automatically because I placed the .sql backup by mistake in it's data directory `/var/lib/mysql`. However, it seems to be not *registered*, since it's not possible to delete it using SQL queries.

Can I just delete `/var/lib/mysql/_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023/nextcloud.sql` to get rid of the `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023` DB or what is a safe way to remove this *pseudo* database?

Comment: This is a relic from MySQL <= 5.0 days. [This page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-database/) suggests - ``ALTER DATABASE `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023` UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;``.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment - _"it was a mysql dump"_. As MariaDB has this schema directory in its internal data dictionary, it would make sense to move or delete the SQL file in that directory, and then try using the previously mentioned `ALTER DATABASE ...` to fix the directory name and internal references. Then you should be able to `DROP` it.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag from your question, since you said you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. I believe it is safe in MariaDB to delete the directly like you did, whereas in MySQL 8.0 and later, it would cause problems, because they changed the implementation of their data dictionary. We should all think of MySQL and MariaDB as totally different, incompatible products.

Comment: @BillKarwin I remember MariaDB to be a drop-in replacement. According to their docs, it is limited since a while. I replaced MySQL by MariaDB years ago, so I didn't really noticed this. Regarding their docs, I'd not agree that they're completely different/incompatible. However, not 1:1 compatible any more. So it seems to be a good idea to avoid the MySQL tag for MariaDB to avoid confusion.

Comment: A MySQL client can talk to a MariaDB server, and vice versa. So they have compatible client/server protocol (at least so far). But they do have different SQL syntax, different builtin functions, different query optimization, different data file formats, different storage engines, and these differences are increasing as they continue to develop features independently. It's a bit like Microsoft SQL Server vs. Sybase. At one time in the distant past, one was a fork of the other. But today no one expects them to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I could delete the *pseudo database* by stopping the container, navigating to the directory of my docker volume and delete the directory, which would be `/var/lib/mysql/_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023` inside the container:

```
rm -rf $volume_path/_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023
```

In my case, I had moved the Docker root directory to a external SSD for VMs & containers

```
docker info | grep "Root Dir"
 Docker Root Dir: /vms/docker-lib
```

So the full path would be `/vms/docker-lib/volumes/mariadb_mysql-data/_data/`. The default is different like `/var/lib/docker` on Ubuntu:

```
docker info | grep "Root Dir"
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

After starting the MariaDB container again, the `#mysql50#_backup-nextcloud-11.05.2023` *database* was gone and also `mysql_upgrade` worked.